# how to hide or show div with ng-show using an array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework

today i'm with an question which goes as follows,
I have an array which has values in terms of Days
below is the example

```
`noDaysArray = ['Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3'];`
```

So on my View i have 3 button Previous Day, Modify and Next Day namely
so i want to show only modify button if `noDaysArray.length == 1` that is if there is one day selected i just show modify button and  its cool my main problem comes to play when array length is more that 1 that is if there is 2 or more days selected i have to display previous and next button and only modify and previous day button in last day and and just modify and next button on first day page

Here is the code i'm using in view

```
<button ng-show="prev" class="button button-small">Prev Day</button>

<button ng-show="Modify" class="button button-small">Modify</button>

<button ng-show="nxt" class="button button-small">Next Day</button>

//Some Day Items

<button class="button button-block" ng-click="btnview()">
Choose</button>
```

And Here goes my Controller code

```
   var nodaysval = [1,2,3,4,5];

   $scope.btnview = function(){

    if(nodaysval.length == 1)
    {
        $scope.prev= false;
        $scope.Modify = true;
        $scope.nxt= false;
    }


    if(nodaysval.length > 1 )
    {

        $scope.hideday = true;
        $scope.hideday2 = true;
        $scope.hideModify = true;
    }
```

I guess this might be a pretty simple issue but any help would be appreciated

Comment: could you be more specific with the use -case ... i understand you need to show the button for prev when are on the last day and next when are on the begining. pls provide more info.

Comment: Sorry about that so here is what i want i'll select start date and end date from previous page according to which i'll generate a array which is called noDaysArray which contains no. of days in array format now i want to generate a dynamic page according to the array generated so if i have have 2 days i should have 2 pages first one with modify and next page button and second with previous and modify button